# VMware View and Workstation 8?

Tags: remote-access, vmware

I was wondering how you can use VMware View on my Nexus 7 to access Shared VMs on Workstation 8.

Do you need to go via Vsphere or is there a way of just accessing it across the wifi network?

Anyone any tips or ideas how it can be done?

Comment: AFAIK VMware view is used to access the Virtual Desktops and not the usual VM.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to access your VMs in this situation is to use VNC, [which VMWare supports out of the box](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-FB23927B-98A0-45E9-BFAC-85152F14BCAC.html). There are plenty of VNC clients for android.

Answer (score 1):

Logmein also works as well as vnc. However what I think you are asking is their a native Virtual machine client for android. The long and short of it is no and you but you can use remote access on your vms to access them on mobile devices. 
The other side of the question I think you are asking is the difference between workstation and vsphere. Vsphere is specifically designed to run servers on server hardware such as server 2003 2008 R2 2012 and s016 server.  where as workstation is designed to run end user operating systems and softwares such as windows xp 7 8 10 and the apps installed on those operating systems. I also can say you can share vmx and virtual machine files over a network and or on the sd card of your nexus using esfile explorer if you are looking to transport your machines from one network to another and access them on machines say at home or work that have VMware on them. I hope this helps clarify what each product is used for and how to share vms across networks.